# ActionBlock seems sometimes to ignore MaxDegreeOfParallelism

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

We are seeing unexpected behavior when posting to an ActionBlock, where parallel processing seems to be occurring even though MaxDegreeOfParallelism is 1. Here is the scenario.

The class that posts to the ActionBlock looks like this:

```
public class ByteHandler {
...
   public ByteHandler(ByteHandlingCallback delegateCallback){
       _byteHandlingActionBlock = new ActionBlock<byte[]>(bytes => delegateCallback.HandleBytes(bytes));
   }


   public void HandleBytes(byte[] bytes){
       _byteHandlingActionBlock.Post(bytes);
   }
```

Downstream, we deserialize the bytes into objects, and pass those objects (let's call them Notifications) to handlers depending on their type:

```
public class NotificationHandler{
   private readonly Dictionary<string, AutoResetEvent> _secondNoticeReceivedEvents;

   public void HandleInitialNotification(InitialNotification notification){
       var secondNoticeReceivedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
       if (!_secondNoticeReceivedEvents.TryAdd(notification.ID, secondNoticeReceivedEvent)) return;

       DoSomethingDownstream(notification);

       if (secondNoticeReceivedEvent.WaitOne(_timeout))
            DoSomethingElseDownstream();
       else
            throw new Exception("Second notification not received within timeout!");

       _secondNoticeReceivedEvents.TryRemove(notification.ID, out secondNoticeReceivedEvent);
   }

   public void HandleSecondNotification(SecondNotification notification){
       AutoResetEvent secondNoticeReceivedEvent;
       if (_secondNoticeReceivedEvents.TryRemove(notification.ID, out secondNoticeReceivedEvent))
            secondNoticeReceivedEvent.Set();
   }
```

This handler has a fatal bug: InitialNotifications come in before their corresponding SecondNotifications, but HandleInitialNotification waits for HandleSecondNotification before exiting, so the thread never reaches HandleSecondNotification.

In general, we see HandleInitialNotification blocking until it times out waiting for HandleSecondNotification, and then execution continues with the pending SecondNotification being handled on the same thread. This is what we normally see in the log:

```
2013-07-05 13:27:25,755 [13] INFO  Received InitialNotification for: XX
2013-07-05 13:27:35,758 [13] WARN  Second notification not not received for XX within timeout!
2013-07-05 13:27:35,761 [13] INFO  Received SecondNotification for: XX
```

This is not the way the code was intended to work, but given the way it was written, it ought always to timeout waiting for the SecondNotification. However, we also occasionally see HandleInitialNotification complete before it times out, with HandleSecondNotification being handled in a timely fashion on a different thread:

```
2013-07-05 13:38:13,232 [56] INFO  Received InitialNotification for: YY
2013-07-05 13:38:13,258 [11] INFO  Received SecondNotification for: YY
```

Since we are using the default ActionBlock, the MaxDegreeOfParallelism should be 1. How is it, then, that a second thread (originating in the ActionBlock) can pick up the SecondNotification while the original thread posted to the ActionBlock is blocking?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your code because of all the levels of abstraction. And you didn't include the most important code: the implementation of `ByteHandlingCallback`. Could you simplify your code as much as you can and then post a short, but complete sample code that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: Sorry not to have responded; unfortunately, I no longer have access to this code to be able to provide the implementation of ByteHandlingCallback. I'll try to edit for simplification, though.

Comment: I am running in the same issue atm

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your timeout/warning happened in almost exactly 10 seconds while all of the other events happen in milliseconds.  It is very likely that you are somehow calling your notification handler methods (HandleInitialNotification & HandleSecondNotification) synchronously so that the actionblock waits for the timeout in HandleInitialNotification to complete before the actionblock grabs the next item in its buffer.  You need to perform your timeout wait asynchronously.

Comment: That is very right, but regrettably it is not the issue that the post was asking about. The original post mentions the same thing--that the code has a fatal flaw because the notification handler methods are being called synchronously. What is mysterious is not why it times out; what is mysterious is why it sometimes *doesn't* time out.